# Managing independent CSS files and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web development and I am using bootstrap to help with making my website. I want to know the best way to manage my own css files and the bootstrap css. I know I can override bootstrap stylings by dropping my own modifications into the style tag, but I feel like this is definitely the best way to go. Currently I just import two style sheets (mine and bootstrap), but they step on each others toes ALOT.

Thanks in advance

Comment: include bootstrap first, then include your own, in that order. Any styles you define in your own stylesheet will override those in bootstrap. Simple.

Comment: you need to write less by less.js

Answer (score 1):

When I use `bootstrap`, I used to follow these 2 rules:

1. Be careful in *naming the* **`class`**.
2. Never use **`!important`** *in your stylesheet*.

Comment: Yes, but say I want to override, let's say the border layout of a span3 class, how would I do that elegantly?

Comment: @ohhh Override it using the same bootstrap class in your stylesheet or you can do it in the bootstrap.css